# Android Release APK crashing after successful gradle assembley

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I migrated my project to Android Studio.  I have no trouble building the app and running from Android Studio.  I have no trouble running the debug APK generated by Android "Generate Signed APK" option.  When I want to build a release APK, I run

```
 gradle assembleRelease
```

Gradle does it's stuff and finishes with BUILD SUCCESSFUL.

When I install this release APK on my device, it crashes immediately due do a missing dependency for (ironically) Crashlytics.  I have added the Crashlytics jar as per their instructions.

I am very confused as to why gradle seems to work in general, but just not for the release.  Any suggestions are really appreciated!

Here is the main build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+'
    compile project(':stripe')

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:extra-abs:+'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.0'

    signingConfigs {

        release {

            storeFile file(****)
            storePassword "****"
            keyAlias "****"
            keyPassword "****"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {

        release {

            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            lib.srcDirs
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Here is the build.gradle for stripe:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java','src/test/java']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/java','src/test/java']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/java','src/test/java']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src/main/java','src/test/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

Comment: have you ticked your jar in your build path thats needed in ecllipse there must be something like that in android studio

Comment: Could you post all your build.gradle files?

Comment: @IllegalArgument I'm not sure if there is somewhere to tick a box for a library dependency.  Like I said, everything builds and runs fine in Android Studio.  I apparently need to run gradle from command line to build a Release-able APK file.  Those APK's build without issue, but crash immediately upon opening the app.

Comment: Was Crashlytics added to the top level project's libs or to your "stripe" module's libs directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hemal from Crashlytics here, I can totally help with this! Go ahead and quickly run through the setup instructions [here](https://www.crashlytics.com/downloads/gradle). That'll take care of the errors you're seeing :)

Comment: Thank you very much!  You guys have great service.

Comment: @Hemal the link you shared is not working. Can you please help with it?